# How to get textareas with content?

Tags: jquery, html

I've got some textareas in my page.

```
<textarea id="first">Some content</textarea>
<textarea id="second"></textarea>
<textarea id="third">other content</textarea>
```

I would like to get all the textareas with any content i.e. except textareas without any content.
In my example, it means first and third textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply combine jQuery's [`not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/%3anot/) with its [`:empty` selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/):

```
$('textarea').not(':empty');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
$("textarea:not(:empty)")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $res = $('textarea').filter(function(i, ele){
    return $(ele).text() != '';
});
```

OR

```
var $res = $('textarea').filter(':not(:empty)');
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qYbvr/     http://jsfiddle.net/qYbvr/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $elements = $('textarea:not(":empty")');


$elements.each(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    alert(element.val());
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/G6LCY/